# Resize Logo Image - Mobile Version

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am a beginner working for a class assignment, I have successfully created the logo and placed it on the top left corner (with your help!) but I noticed that on the mobile version, the logo gets bigger and blurry (see picture please!). I would like to keep it very small at the top of the homepage but I don't really know how to!

This is the link for my website: http://gabrielr.sgedu.site/final-project/

Any help please[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8jpe.png)

Comment: Please post the code you have written **in the question itself** so we can help you fix it.

Comment: show us some code html/css or maybe recreate the issue on fiddle or here on the code runner.

Answer (score 2):

Your element `h1.site-header__title` is on `display: inline-block` if the width is 55em or bigger. When is less than that, it defaults back to `display: block` which makes it take the full width. Then you have all `img` tags with a `width: 100%` which means that *even if the image is smaller than the full width of the parent element*, it's going to still expand it, which causes your pixelation.

In general it's good to just keep the `max-width: 100%` for images, to prevent unintended pixelation.

Another solution for your issue in particular, if you don't want to change that rule, would be to limit the max width of either the img or the `h1.site-header__title`, with either a `width` or a `max-width` rule.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I used the .h1.site-header__title and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

write size for image...

```
   h1.site-header__title img {
        width: 92px;
    }
```